# BeatsX on Windows 7

Tags: drivers

I have BeatsX earbuds (bluetooth wireless headphones), and I am able to get them to work on my phone and Windows 10 laptop, but not my desktop running Windows 7. They show up in device manager with a yellow exclamation mark and I am unable to find a driver for them. Is there not a driver somewhere that I can manually install to get these to work?

Comment: Required additional drivers/software for Bluetooth devices in Windows 7 were typically downloaded on demand from the Windows Update service. This was the case particularly with audio devices. Try right-clicking in the device with the exclamation mark and "update driver".

Comment: I tried adding the device again - even after searching Windows Update it displays "No driver found" (however it does install "Standard Serial over Bluetooth link").

Comment: It should be installing BT Audio... I suggest testing it in another Windows 7, if available. There's a chance it isn't compatible with older OSes.